# Can't get pam_time.so to work with http

Tags: authentication, ubuntu-12.04, pam

The `/etc/security/time.conf` man page contains this example:

```
All users except for root are denied access to console-login at all times:

    login ; tty* & !ttyp* ; !root ; !Al0000-2400
```

For this to work, `/etc/pam.d/login` needs to have a line

```
account    requisite  pam_time.so
```

This example works, and I tried to adapt it to limit HTTP access from the console rather than `login`. I added

```
http ; tty* & !ttyp* ; !root ; !Al0000-2400 # will fix "time" later
```

to `/etc/security/time.conf`, and created `/etc/pam.d/http` with

```
account    requisite  pam_time.so
```

This doesn't work. I can still use `wget` as non-root from the console. Am I doing something wrong?

---

Here are some examples where people claim to be using PAM to restrict **HTTP** (!) access (I couldn't get them to work, so I wanted to start with something simpler, as in the above) :

- https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/7260/how-to-configure-user-restriction-with-pam-a-kind-of-parental-control/
- [How do I restrict my kids' computing time?](https://askubuntu.com/a/70277/121652) This *+20* AskUbuntu answer shows both "login" and "http" examples:

  ```
  login ; * ; !bobby ; MoTuWeThFr0800-2000
  login ; * ; !root ; !Al0000-2400
  http ; * ; !bobby ; MoTuWeThFr0800-2000
  http ; * ; !root; !Al0000-2400
  ```

Comment: PAM is not the right solution for what you're trying to do.  PAM is designed to handle various aspects of logging in and creating a 'session'.  It does not define what you can do once you're in a session.  The apps that are using pam have to be written to actually use pam.  If the person is already on the console on the command line, it's too late for PAM.  If what you're trying to do is to block the http protocol at a network level, you should be looking at your firewall.

Comment: You could accomplish this with netfilter's "time" and "owner" modules.

Comment: @yoonix You should post that as an answer :-)

Comment: @yoonix I added some references where people claim to be restricting HTTP with PAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have tried to drive the point home (and are correct), but I'm going to focus on the cited examples that are leading you astray and how they have no relevance to the command you are running as your test. (`wget`)

PAM is not a magical thing that lives at the kernel level; individual applications have to call the PAM stack in order for it to make a decision about whether or not some kind of access is permitted. Even then, the application must provide its own logic to implement whatever decision that the PAM library makes.

In the examples you're citing, access is being denied to any applications that call the PAM library and identify themselves with a service type of `http`. Unless the application is explicitly configured to link to the PAM library, this will accomplish all of nothing.

To further prove the point, here are the libraries that `wget` on my Debian system is linked against. Note the absence of anything with the acronym "pam".

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/wget
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77c5000)
    libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0xb776c000)
    libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0xb7614000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb7610000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb7606000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb74bf000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb74ab000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77c6000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7492000)
```

No PAM library anywhere in that. Meanwhile, here's `/bin/login` and `/usr/sbin/sshd`...note the presence of `libpam.so.0`:

```
$ ldd /bin/login
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7723000)
    libpam.so.0 => /lib/libpam.so.0 (0xb770a000)
    libpam_misc.so.0 => /lib/libpam_misc.so.0 (0xb7707000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb75c0000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb75bb000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/i686/cmov/libcrypt.so.1 (0xb7589000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7724000)

$ ldd /usr/sbin/sshd
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77c0000)
    libwrap.so.0 => /lib/libwrap.so.0 (0xb7737000)
    libpam.so.0 => /lib/libpam.so.0 (0xb772b000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0xb7710000)
    libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0xb75b7000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/i686/cmov/libutil.so.1 (0xb75b3000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb759f000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/i686/cmov/libcrypt.so.1 (0xb756d000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0xb753e000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0xb748b000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0xb7488000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7341000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/i686/cmov/libnsl.so.1 (0xb732a000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb7326000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77c1000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0xb7302000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0xb72fb000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/libkeyutils.so.1 (0xb72f8000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libresolv.so.2 (0xb72e4000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb72cb000)
```

Unless you are designing a very specific solution that involves an application linked to PAM making calls to the `http` service, this will not accomplish what you are trying to make it do.

Full-disclosure: There is nothing to stop any of the programs you run `ldd` against from dynamically loading a code module that is linked to PAM. (`wget` is not designed with a modular architecture, so the logic here still holds)

Comment: Thanks! Would I be correct in concluding then that the "http" example in my second link (parental control) is mistaken? (*E.g.* `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` does not link to PAM in Ubuntu, so this parental control attempt wouldn't accomplish anything)

Comment: @MaxB Unfortunately, there's no provided context for what application they're attempting to control by limiting the `http` service. (correct me if I'm wrong, I did try to locate it) So the only thing that can be really said is "that might have worked for what they were doing".

Comment: I'll ask *hhlp* what he tried to accomplish there.

Comment: ... never mind. I don't have enough karma to comment in AskUbuntu

Answer (score 1):

The PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) is for *user* authentication, i.e., it has to do with users logging in to the system. HTTP has nothing whatsoever to do here.

Comment: I added references where people claim to be restricting HTTP with PAM.